# Can't Move PTZ Camera using ONVIF Protocol -Python Client

Tags: python, camera, wsdl, onvif, zeep

I am trying to move a ptz camera using the onvif client wrote in [python from github](https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep)
I can connect to the camera Bosh 7000 Autodome. I am using the example to test [move operation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep/zeep/examples/continuous_move.py) Here is my object to use like argument for the ContinuousMove method

```
>>> moverequest
{
    'ProfileToken': '0',
    'Velocity': {
        'PanTilt': {
            'x': 0.57,
            'y': -0.44,
            'space': 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/PanTiltSpaces/PositionGenericSpace'
        },
        'Zoom': {
            'x': 0.0,
            'space': 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/ZoomSpaces/PositionGenericSpace'
        }
    },
    'Timeout': None
}
```

When I try to execute ContinuousMove() I got the next error

```
>>> ptz.ContinuousMove(moverequest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/Documents/python-onvif-zeep/onvif/client.py", line 25, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/Documents/python-onvif-zeep/onvif/client.py", line 150, in wrapped
    return call(params, callback)
  File "/home/myuser/Documents/python-onvif-zeep/onvif/client.py", line 138, in call
    ret = func(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 130, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 195, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 362, in process_error
    subcodes=subcodes,
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Action Failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/Documents/python-onvif-zeep/onvif/client.py", line 27, in wrapped
    raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Action Failed
```

HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

You are using `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/PanTiltSpaces/PositionGenericSpace` and `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/ZoomSpaces/PositionGenericSpace` . According to §5.7.1.1 of the [PTZ service spec](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/ptz/ONVIF-PTZ-Service-Spec.pdf):

> The generic pan/tilt  position space shall  be  provided  by  every 
>   PTZ  node  that  supports  absolute  pan/tilt, since it does not
>   relate to a specific physical range. Instead, the range should be
>   defined as the  full  range  of  the  PTZ  unit  normalized  to  the 
>   range  -1  to  1

In section 5.7.3.1 you'll find

> The generic pan/tilt  velocity space shall  be  provided  by  every 
>   PTZ  node,  since  it  does  not  relate to a specific physical range.
>   Instead, the range should be defined as a range of the PTZ unit’s
>   speed normalized to the range -1 to 1, where a positive velocity would
>   map to clockwise rotation or movement in the right/up direction.

Thus try using `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/PanTiltSpaces/VelocityGenericSpace` and `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tptz/ZoomSpaces/VelocityGenericSpace`.